# Language structure problem in localization for flutter?

Tags: flutter, localization, flutter-intl

I am using localization in flutter.

this is the eng text: `placed for $date`

this is the translated text: `$date का लागि राखिएको`

as you can see the text has a variable (date) in it and as the grammar structure for the two language is different the variable has to be placed in different position.

```
AppLocalizations.of(context).placed_for + date.toString()
// The usual way of doing this does not work due to different placing of the date variable.
```

How do i handle such case? Do I have to write custom logic or is there already a way to handle such case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not used to work with the AppLocalizations itself, but it seems to work the same way as intl.

If so, just edit your arb files to receive the desired parameters:

```
"placed_for": "placed for {date}", 
"placed_for": "{date}  का लागि राखिएको",
```

then you should be able to use it in the following way:

```
AppLocalizations.of(context).placed_for(date.toString())
```

Edit:

You also need to add the placeholder definition to your arb template. Example:

```
{
  "helloWorld": "Hello {name}!",
  "@helloWorld": {
    "description": "The conventional newborn programmer greeting",
    "placeholders": {
      "name": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Then, after adding the `placeholders`, you can use the generated string using:

```
AppLocalizations.of(context).helloWorld('Leandro'),
```

PS. You can also add multiples placeholders